# Best way to define user session data in Vue using Laravel and Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm developing a app with a dynamic menu using Laravel, Vue and Inertia.

In order to pass the session information about the menu (which itens should be showed, icons, etc) and user data (avatar and name), actually i use the *HandleInertiaRequests* middleware.

However, this way, all the information is sent in every Inertia request, which, i believe, its far from perfect.

So, it's there some kind of strategy that allows to send the session information only once, preferably, in the login fase?

Comment: You want to pass the session value to specific route instead of to all routes?

Comment: No, not specific route session values.
I'm referring to global app information, such as current user logged name, avatar, and main menu items which that specific logged user can access. This kind of data only needs to be sent on the login moment, since from that point forward is static.
Nowadays i use the HandleInertiaRequests middleware to send that information to the app, but this as the inconvenient of being sent in every Inertia request.
My question is to try to understand if there's a way of send this kind of data only once...

Comment: ok, so you mean to say that after login the data is static which you want to access on each component. but you don't want to send that static data on each request's response in form of session. Right?

Comment: Yes, its exactly that!

Comment: then there are two ways to handle this situation. The first way is to use the `vuex` state management library. so once the user logged in then sets that static value to the state and uses it in any component. but this way, if on another tab if the user's role/permission or icons change then until the user logged in next time, he will always get the stale data.

Comment: the second way - set the response header as a JSON string and put that JSON string to the state. in this case, you will always get fresh data. but the response payload will increase. so here you can check in some special URLs where you need the fresh data otherwise skip the response header.

Comment: Ok! Thank you.
I'll give a try to both options...

Answer (score 1):

In this case i'll store user details in `vuex` from `MasterLayout.vue`. The layout should be `mounted` only after user is logged in.

In `MasterLayout.vue`;

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
...
mounted() {
 this.$store.dispatch("setUser");
}
</script>
```

Now, in `auth.js`;

```
export const auth = {
state: () => ({
    user: [],
}),

actions: {
    setUser({ commit }) {
        commit("SET_USER");
    },
},

mutations: {
    async SET_USER(state) {
        await axios
            .get(route("user"))
            .then((response) => {
                state.user = response.data;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    },
},

getters: {
    auth(state) {
        return state.user;
    },
  },
};
```

Now, in `Avatar.vue` component;

```
  <template>
    //do anything with data
    {{auth.name}}
    {{auth.email}}
  </template>

  <script>
    computed: {
     ...mapGetters(["auth"]),
    },
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you... That's almost the solution i've adopted, but definitively better...